# Safari and CORS: Custom Response Headers disappear

Tags: ajax, safari, cors, asp.net-web-api

I've recreated my error as simply as possible, and it goes like this:

I have a c# Web Api project and I installed the CORS Web Api nuget package.  I then added this to the Register function of the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I then created a really simple "GetToken" api, pasted below:

```
[Route("~/api/auth/token")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetToken()
{
    var result = new
    {
        FirstName = "matt"
    };
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Authorization", "test");

    //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS");
    //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://run.plnkr.co/");
    return response;
}
```

The commented out code is just some of the many combinations of Header configurations I used to try and solve this problem.  After the web api, I created an extremely basic api call in plunker:

```
var Test1 = function() {
    $.ajax("http://localhost:61826/api/auth/token", {
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {  
            debugger;
        },
        error: function(err) {
            debugger;
        },
        crossDomain: true
    });
}
```

I also created a version in angular, which I'll share if anybody needs it.

The end result. In chrome, it works wonderfully, as you can see here (Authorization header is there):

[image]

But in Safari it doesn't work, as you can see here (Authorization header missing):
[image]

I've been banging my head against the wall for a number of days on this one, and it's time to bring in the community. Can anybody tell me what the heck is going on??

Comment: Did you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hey instead of setting the expose headers manually have you tried doing it like this

```
//set in the webapiconfig
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "Authorization"));   

[Route("~/api/auth/token")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetToken()
{
var result = new
{
    FirstName = "matt"
};
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
response.Headers.Add("Authorization", "test");
return response;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks for the response.  I just tried your suggestion but no luck.  Same behavior (chrome fine, safari the header simply doesn't appear).

Comment: Have you looked in the network tab do u see it in the response header?

Comment: Two more things to try 1) try doing in js getResponseHeader("Authorization") instead of the get all 2)try adding something to the response body if it's blank 3) try bypassing jquery and using regular js to make the request. I suspect it's a client side issue

Comment: Hi Dev, thanks again for the quick responses.

Interestingly, the Safari network tab does pick up the Authorization header. It just doesn't get digested by the ajax success function.  

I've tried just doing getResponseHeader("Authorization"), and no luck.

I've added something to the response body, and that gets picked up.

I'm working on bypassing jquery now.  I'll post the results very soon.

Comment: Hi Dev,  I tried bypassing jquery, but still no luck.  The header doesn't appear.  The code I used to bypass jquery is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HVf8HvEunTbW2TVQRc9T?p=preview

Comment: @DevTeamExpress can you help me a litle with my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018621/angularjs-headers-not-added-in-my-rest-using-safari